# graphic arts for software engineers

Tags: photoshop, graphic

Can anyone recommend a good ebook, website, self-study course, etc. to help software engineers, programmers, etc. gain a basic knowledge of graphic arts.  I'm interested in basic Photoshop/GIMP skills to help make and tweak icons, images, etc. when I don't have a professional graphic artist nearby to help out or if the job is too small to hire one.

Comment: Is this question on-topic here? I don't think it is, but I'm not sure.

Comment: do you mean is it appropriate for this website?  Well, I stumbled across a question asking about the best book for programmers, and it was wildly popular.  I figured it wouldn't hurt to find the best graphics tutorial for programmers as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you're wanting is to actually learn graphic design, well that's a big topic. However for simply learning how to tweak images in Photoshop there are plenty of great free resources online. Here's one of the first results when I just searched for "photoshop beginner tutorials"

http://mashable.com/2010/08/12/12-beginner-tutorials-for-getting-started-with-photoshop/

Also, you'll find lots of great info at the graphic design Stack Exchange site:

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: not graphic design, but learn what you're talking about.  just basic skills.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I read [Graphic Design Essentials: Skills, Software and Creative Solutions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136052355), its a bit on the pricy side, but it was very worth it. It explained everything I needed to know. I wasnt the best with Graphics at first but this book gave me such a great overview, I was easily able to jump into it.